# How do I blur the border of my image div?

Tags: html, css

Can somebody help me in this?

I have tried box shadow and border but couldn't get the transparency in the border:

```
<div class="" style="border-radius: 125px;
                     width: 125px;
                     height: 125px;
                     margin: auto;
                     box-shadow: 0 0 0 6px rgba(68,68,68,0.25), 0 0 0 15px rgba(68,68,68,0.35); ">
<img src="images/tracks_bg.png" width="100%" height="100%" style="border-radius: 50%; opacity: 1 !important;">
</div>
```

[image: I want the blur border as displayed in screen shot]

Comment: Please post code in your question, whatever you have tried.

Comment: I have tried it using box shadow as below:

<div class="" style="
    border-radius: 125px;
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    margin: auto;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 6px rgba(68,68,68,0.25), 0 0 0 15px rgba(68,68,68,0.35);
"><img src="images/tracks_bg.png" width="100%" height="100%" style="
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 1 !important;
"></div>

Comment: Please edit the question. Code in comments is virtually unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could

- Use a wrapper DIV
- Inside your wrapper place an absolutely positioned (full-size) **blurred** DIV
- Inside your wrapper place a **circle** with the same background image as the blurred DIV
- Play with `box-shadow` n the circle track image DIV element

```css
/*QuickReset*/ *{margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;} html,body{height:100%;font:14px/1.4 sans-serif;}

.player {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #000; 
}

.trackImageBlur {
  position: absolute;
  background: none 50% 50% / cover;
  opacity:0.6; /* lower opacity so we can transpare the parent's #000 bg */
  padding: 4vw; margin: -4vw; /* prevent seeing blurred-out edges */
  box-sizing: content-box; /* apply normal paddings (on the outside) */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.trackImage {
  position: absolute;
  background: none 50% 50% / 150%;
  width: 60vh;
  height: 60vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow:
  0 0 0 20vh rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
  0 0 0 12vh rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
  0 0 0 9vh rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
  0 0 0 3vh rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="player">
  <div class="trackImageBlur" style="background-image:url('//i.stack.imgur.com/ItuWP.png')"></div>
  <div class="trackImage" style="background-image:url('//i.stack.imgur.com/ItuWP.png')"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I'm currently using this box-shadow css code and it works fine for me

box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);